# Quick way to denote the different solutions of an equation.

Tags: notation

Let's say that we conclude from $u^2+u-2=0$ that (over $\mathbb R$) $$u=- \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2}$$

What are the notational possibilities for this situation? Should I write

$$u^2+u-2 =0$$
$$\iff u=- \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2}$$
$$\iff (u=-2\lor u=1)$$

or can I write

$$\iff u=- \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2}\in\{-2,1\}$$

or something like that? Mostly I wanted to know whether there exists a short yet formally correct way of saying "$u$ can be this and that". Especially when $u$ can take on more than two values.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it depend upon the last expression you get. If your expression can't be simplified as in $x=1\pm\sqrt{2}$, then use the "$\pm$" notation. Otherwise, as in $x=1\pm\sqrt{4}$, add an equivalent statement such as $x=3 \vee x=-1$, or even $x=3,-1$ which the same by convention.

Comment: I never dared to write $u=-2,1$, thinking of it as a no-go.